# Why do I only see three-state workflow? How to add more?

Tags: workflow

I have a Sharepoint 2010 site hosted by a company, I am the admin and have all the rights. My questions is I only see one workflow three-state is this because I'm not using Moss and is there any way around it?

I would like to create a time-off request based on a calendar and Three-state is not the best option.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 1):

John,

By your question it sounds like you are running SharePoint 2010 but you say MOSS.  Can you clarify the version?  Do you you have the ability to connect to the hosting site using SharePoint Designer 2010?  What I would do is go down the path of Designer and look into putting together a simple workflow using the rule driven wizard.  A lot of good resources out there.  A lot more flexible than any of the OOTB workflows.  IMHO.  However, if you are stuck using the canned workflows, look to see if any features need to be enabled.

Paul

Comment: Just confirmed that it might be as easy as enabling the SharePoint 2007 workflow feature at the collection level.

Answer (score 1):

Since the site is hosted, the provider might have blocked access to Sharepoint Designer and therefore your ability to create workflows.  Check with the host to ensure that they have not blocked access to the program.  If they haven't, then you can download Sharepoint Designer and create workflows.  If they have, then your stuck with the 3 state workflow of Sharepoint Foundations.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have installed SharePoint foundation 2010.
SharePoint foundation 2010 shows only three state workflow.
if u want to create workflow, u can take help of SharePoint designer or u can do it by coding in visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ashish has it correct. THis is Sharepoint Foundation 2010. I do have designer now and downloaded the Visio last night. I will have to do some testing. thanks for the quick answer all.

John